# jQuery - Combining elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to combine the location of my WordPress theme folder to a jQuery element. I haven't used jQuery much before and I've done a little research but haven't found anything of value.

Here's my JavaScript variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">var templateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>";
```

And I'm wanting to add 'templateDir' to this:

```
$next = $('<li><a href="#" class="next" class="controls"><img src="images/right_button.png" border="0" /></a></li>');
```

Ideally I thought it would be something like this, but it just errors.

```
$next = $('<li><a href="#" class="next" class="controls"><img src="' + templateDir + 'images/right_button.png" border="0" /></a></li>');
```

So I'm not quite sure how it works. Thanks.

**Update:** Fixed the issue. Seems it was all down to the jQuery file not being first. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, combine `class="next" class="controls"` into `class="next controls"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$next = $('<li><a href="#" class="next controls"><img src="' + templateDir + 'images/right_button.png" border="0" /></a></li>');
```

That is, using a single 'class' attribute. Maybe that is what is causing error

UPDATE:

Make sure you have jquery library file included at the beginning before calling the reference functions.

Comment: With that I'm getting: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < /website/page/2/:16
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined basic-jquery-slider.js:385
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined jquery.dropdownPlain.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function

Comment: Are you including the jquery library file before calling the references?